# how to implement regions/code collapse in javascript using intel xdk?

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

how can we use regions/code collapse in javascript using intel xdk because it will be handy way for easy mantanes and make the code easy to understand and write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use your own editor with your XDK project files, it is not a requirement that you use the built-in editor, although there are a few features that require the built-in Brackets editor to work.

If you are using the built-in Brackets editor, you will find some extensions under the file menu. There is a "Code Folding" extension that I think is what you are looking for. Also, I highly recommend you install the various lint/hint extensions, they are very helpful for finding subtle issues with your code.

Comment: thanks yes i found an "Code Folding" extension

File -> Extension Manager
Code Folding extension -> install.
ctr+alt+C/X for collapse/expand